# Jitter while screen recording with avconv

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, gnome-shell, avconv, screencasting

I've figured out how to record decent quality with `avconv` now, the problem that remains which I also have experienced with `ffmpeg` and `recordmydesktop` is that my desktop background keeps flickering through. I've disabled the desktop effects in Linux Mint 16 Petra, running Cinnamon.

This is how it looks:

[image: Jitter]

How can I avoid this? Should I use another Desktop Environment like XFCE?

The command I am using:

```
$ avconv -f alsa -ac 2 -i plughw:2,0 -f x11grab -s 1920x1080 \
    -r 30 -i :0.0 -acodec libvorbis -ar 44100 -vcodec huffyuv grab.avi
```